# Add, modify and delete entry in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

[Please see the image of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKRKf.png)

This is my application.

I enter the medicine name and it will captured in the `<li>` items.

I have 2 concerns.

First: When I click add without entering any data, null values get stored, which I don't want, I want an alert to display.

Second: whenever I want to edit the data, it should re-enter in the respective files of form and I can edit and saved.

Code are as follows:

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 center1">
            <div class="col-xs-12  ">
                <h4 class="text-center txtC1">Enter your medicines</h4> 
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                <input type="text"  ng-model="enteredName" id="enter"/>
            </div>
<br/>&nbsp
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center ">




<p class="rr txtC2">Type</p>
<div class="rr">
                    <select id="dd" ng-model="sel">
                        <option value="Days">Days</option>
                        <option value="Tabs">Tab</option>
                        <option value="Packs">Pack</option>
                    </select>



</div>
<p class="rr txtC2">Qty</p>

                <input type="number" class="rr" ng-model="ww" id="dd"/> 



            </div>


    <br/>&nbsp
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center ">

                <button id="btn2" ng-Click="addName()">Add</button>
                <button id="btn2">Order</button>
            </div>      




    <br/>&nbsp

<div class="col-xs-12">
<p class="txtC1">Cart<hr></p>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 dd1" >

    <ul class="list-unstyled" >
        <li class="tt" ng-repeat="name in names">{{name.x1}} x {{name.tp}} x {{name.qty}}

<span class="fa fa-close tt1" ng-click="removeName(name)"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-edit tt1" ng-click="edit(name)"></span></li>

    </ul>


    <div>







    </div>              
</div>
```

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


 app.controller('NameCtrl', function ($scope){
        $scope.names = [

        ];

        $scope.addName = function() {

          $scope.names.push({'x1':$scope.enteredName,'tp':$scope.sel,          'qty':$scope.ww});



          $scope.enteredName = '';

 $scope.ww = '';
 $scope.tp = '';

 console.log( $scope.sel) ;         
        };

        $scope.removeName = function(name) {
          var i = $scope.names.indexOf(name);
          $scope.names.splice(i, 1);
        };

      $scope.edit = function(name){

           var i = $scope.names.indexOf(name);

        $scope.enteredName = ($scope.names[i]);

           $scope.names.splice(i, 1);

           console.log( $scope.enteredName[i])

      }



      });
```

Comment: Instead of image, post demo plunkr.

Comment: Post your code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/JDPqHfgMzSBHsa9InHxi?p=preview

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ux67279x/

Comment: $scope.edit = function(name){ $scope.enteredName = name.x1; $scope.sel = name.tp; $scope.ww = name.qty;
$scope.names.splice(i, 1);}

Comment: Just look at my answer down below, it works

Comment: Yeah it works now...Many Thanks!

Comment: But i need one more help

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/JDPqHfgMzSBHsa9InHxi?p=preview

Comment: Autocomplete methode is giving me the list, but it is not saving the entire string in the model

Comment: You could look into [bootstrap typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)

Comment: YEs......http://plnkr.co/edit/YGQXog9D66nWAAzarToF?p=preview

Comment: Check this : http://plnkr.co/edit/YGQXog9D66nWAAzarToF?p=preview            When i am editing the entry it will going back to the form but soon it hit enter the null values are being saved....

Answer (score 0):

Changed name and stuff for it to make sense for me, but this works (edit and removal, not alert when empty)

html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="NameCtrl">

<h4 class="text-center txtC1">Enter your medicines</h4> 
<input type="text" ng-model="item.name" id="enter"/> <br>

<b>Type</b> <br>
<select ng-model="item.type">
    <option value="Days">Days</option>
    <option value="Tabs">Tab</option>
    <option value="Packs">Pack</option>
</select> <br>

<b >Amount</b> <br>
<input type="number" class="rr" ng-model="item.amount" /> <br>

<hr>

<button id="btn2" ng-Click="addItem()">Add</button>
<button id="btn2">Order</button> <br>

<hr>

<b >Cart</b>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}} : {{item.type}} : {{item.amount}}
        <a class="fa fa-close tt1" ng-click="deleteItem($index)">remove</a>
        <a class="fa fa-edit tt1" ng-click="edit(item)">edit</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


app.controller('NameCtrl', function ($scope){
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.item = {
        name: '',
        type: '',
        amount: ''
    };

    $scope.addItem = function() {
        $scope.items.push($scope.item);

        $scope.item = {
            name: '',
            type: '',
            amount: ''
        };
    };

    $scope.deleteItem = function(index) {
      $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
    };

    $scope.edit = function(item, index){
      $scope.item = item;
      $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
    };
 });
```

Update:
For the alert notice you could do something like this:

```
$scope.addItem = {

// checks if any of item name, type or amount is an empty string ('')
// and if it is, show alert message
if ($scope.item.name == '' || $scope.item.type == '' || $scope.item.amount == '' ) {
     alert('Fill in all fields');
} else {
    // function to add item to items
}
```

Comment: Check this : plnkr.co/edit/YGQXog9D66nWAAzarToF?p=preview When i am editing the entry it will going back to the form but soon it hit enter the null values are being saved....

Comment: @SaurabhDellaRa'Man I think it can be because you are not pushing the whole object (name title and name value) to your 'cart' list, so when retrieving the item to edit, you don't get the all the values, you only get the text. But I haven't had time to look through it